# Cross comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to achieve something.  I have an Object, and if I do the following

```
let str = JSON.stringify(this.data, null, 4);
console.log(str);
```

The output I receive is this (I have removed a lot of elements, just displaying one in each.

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "source": "0",
            "target": "5",
            "value": "123",
        }
    ],
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": 93,
            "node": "0",
            "name": "pizza",
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to push this data onto an Array, as such I am doing

```
Object.entries(this.data.links).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    this.newArray.push([val.source, val.target, parseInt(val.value)]);
});
```

Now obviously this is only pushing the links onto my array, which is what I need.  This is doing something like the following

```
0: (3) ["0", "5", 123, __ob__: Observer]
```

Now although this is the structure I require, instead of it being 0 and 5, I need it to use the name element which matches the correct node. So the above should be

```
0: (3) ["pizza", "pie", 123, __ob__: Observer]
```

As node 0 in the nodes array is pizza and node 5 is pie (although I dont have it displayed above).

So how can I cross check the source and target from the links with the node in nodes, and then use the name as the value?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have an easier time if you first build a map of nodes. `this.data.nodes.forEach(n=>nodeMap[n.node] = n.name);` - now you can just reference `nodeMap[val.source]`.

Comment: Could you please edit your question, click the `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily convert the `nodes` array such that it returns you the `name` by providing it with index.

```
nodes = [];
data.nodes.forEach(node=>nodes[node.node] = node.name);
```

Then in your `forEach`

```
// this might give you undefined at some places, so make sure you have all the values, or put in some necessory checks.
Object.entries(this.data.links).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    this.newArray.push([nodes[val.source], nodes[val.target], parseInt(val.value)]);
});
```

Comment: `nodes` should be object (or Map) not array

Comment: @charlie Does it matter?

Comment: @charlietfl yeah, my mistake. though the code will still work, just that the array would have a lot of empty spaces :D, on the other hand, object/map has a larger memory footprint :P